# Fading in char by char (keeping DOM intact)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate a text so that it fades in character by character. I actually managed to do this without keeping the DOM intact and it looks like this:

```
// make each character an own span element
// abc will become <span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span>
var elements = $(elemId).text().split('');
$(elemId).text('');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    $(elemId).append('<span>' + elements[i] + '</span>');
}

// fade in all spans one by one
$(elemId + " span").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(speed * index).fadeIn(300);
});
```

But this breaks possible elements within my text, especially strong, but also lists or tables. So I thought about these two possible solutions:

- Traverse the DOM with jQuery and wrap each character with a `<span>`, but do not delete the other elements. Then we still have the problem, that the table rows will always be displayed (just empty)
- Traverse the DOM with jQuery and wrap each character with a `<span>` and disable each other element to `display: none`. Then retraverse it and show stuff as it comes along (both `span` and other elements). This might break HTML for a while (`<ul>` without `<li>` inside etc., but I guess all browsers will be able to handle it well enough).

I started with `contents()` method, but I did not really get on.

This is what I currently have, but it does not replace anything at all (even though it finds some text at least):

```
$(elemId).contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType == 3) {
        var elements = $(this).text().split('');
        alert(elements);
        // does not delete anything, but it would also break 
        // if it deleted something
        // because text('') goes over elements like <strong> etc.
        $(this).text('');
        alert($(this).text());

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            $(this).append('<span>' + elements[i] + '</span>');
        }
    }
});
```

So what do I have to do to get my text and tags correctly? If everything is set up like above, I guess it’s just a matter of using `contents()` recursively and set visibility on all elements again. But adding my `<span>` properly seems difficult.

### Some example

```
I am <strong>AB</strong>
```

Should become:

```
<span display="none">I</span><span display="none"> </span>
<span ...>a</span><span ...>m</span><span ...> </span>
<strong ...><span ...>A</span><span ...>B</span></strong>
```

Comment: what about using overlays that'd fade out ?

Comment: @mikakun: I think I was not able to find exactly what you mean, but it sounds like it does not work, because then the whole layout should have to be prerendered (like in `visibility: hidden`), but I want my text-box to grow with the text (`display: none`).

Comment: i meant you overlay elements with a background over the text (text visible but hidden by overlay); what about animating width of your text container (with a gradient border that'd mimick a kind of fade, some no wrap & overflow hidden) (not possible if more than one line though); your chosen path seem a bit overwhelming for such a tiny feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.contents()` doesn't traverse the DOM. You need to apply `.find("*")` to get all the descendants and then apply `.contents()` on them.

```
$("selector").find("*").andSelf().contents().each(function(){
  if(this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE){
    $(this).replaceWith($.map(this.data, function(c){
      return "<span>" + c + "</span>";
    }).join(""));
  }
});
```

This is a work done per character in the element's descendants. I suppose you are aware that you need to use with extreme care.

Comment: Was able to extend it to also hide the tags (e.g. ordered lists) by adding another `else if` :)